# How can I use recycler viewer with a fragment on a tablayout (android studio Kotlin)?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The error in "adapter = UserAdapter(users)" says type mismatch required: context "Change parameter Context type of primary constructor of class UserAdapter to ArrayList" I tried running it while the "adapter = UserAdapter(users)" is enclosed as a comment (like so //adapter = UserAdapter(users)) in shows an error in logcat saying "java.lang.NullPointerException: v.findViewById(R.id.RVusermain) must not be null
at com.example.chattrialskot.fragments.Year1.onCreateView(Year1.kt:49) ".

> USERS.kt

```
class Users {

var userstuID: String? = null;
var username: String? = null;
var useremail: String? = null;
var useraccstat: String? = null;
var useruid: String? = null;
var useryear: String? = null;

constructor(){}

constructor(userstuID: String?, username: String?, useremail: String?, useraccstat: String?,
            useruid: String?, useryear: String?){

    this.userstuID = userstuID
    this.username = username
    this.useremail = useremail
    this.useraccstat = useraccstat
    this.useruid = useruid
    this.useryear = useryear
} }
```

> USER ADAPTER

```
class UserAdapter(var UAContext: Context, var userlist: ArrayList<Users>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UsersViewHolder> (){

fun UserAdapter(userlist: ArrayList<Users>, mContext: Context){

    this.userlist = userlist
    this.UAContext = mContext
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UsersViewHolder {

    val view:View = LayoutInflater.from(UAContext).inflate(
        R.layout.userlayout, parent,
        false)
    return UserAdapter.UsersViewHolder(view)

}
```

> FRAGMENT

```
class Year1 : Fragment() {

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): Year1 {
        return Year1()
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_year1, container, false)

    userrecyclerviewer = v.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.RVyear1)
    userrecyclerviewer.setHasFixedSize(true)
    userrecyclerviewer.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    userrecyclerviewer.adapter = adapter

    users = ArrayList()
    adapter = UserAdapter(users) 
    getUsers()
    return v
}

private fun getUsers(){

    FireAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    FireDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

    FireDB.child("users").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            users.clear()

            for(postSnapshot in snapshot.children){

                val userfrmDB = postSnapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)

                if(FireAuth.currentUser?.uid != userfrmDB?.useruid
                    && userfrmDB?.useraccstat != "Banned")
                {
                    users.add(userfrmDB!!)
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}}
```

Comment: you have to pass context to the UserAdapter() while creating object. you can do something like ---> adapter = UserAdapter(context, users)

Comment: In `onCreateViewHolder`, you can use `parent.context` to get context

Comment: @RudraRokaya is this what I should do? adapter = UserAdapter(context?, users) and also I changed the adapter to class UserAdapter(var UAContext: Context?, var userlist: ArrayList<Users>):

Comment: yeah, something like that.Did you try to run your code? any errors let me know.

Comment: @RudraRokaya Hi thanks for the tip a while ago it removed the error of adapter = UserAdapter(context?, users). but now when I run it it throws an error of java.lang.NullPointerException: v.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.RVusermain) must not be null

Comment: please, follow the code below. You were getting that error because you were initializing the adapter after you had attached the adapter to the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Year1 : Fragment() {

companion object {
  fun newInstance(): Year1 {
      return Year1()
  } 
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
 ): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_year1, container, false)

    userrecyclerviewer = v.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.RVusermain)
    userrecyclerviewer.setHasFixedSize(true)
    getUsers()
    users = ArrayList()
    userrecyclerviewer.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    adapter = UserAdapter(context?, users) 
    userrecyclerviewer.adapter = adapter

    return v
}

private fun getUsers(){

   FireAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
   FireDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

   FireDB.child("users").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{

    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        users.clear()

        for(postSnapshot in snapshot.children){

            val userfrmDB = postSnapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)

            if(FireAuth.currentUser?.uid != userfrmDB?.useruid
                && userfrmDB?.useraccstat != "Banned")
            {
                users.add(userfrmDB!!)
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
    }
  })
}

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 }}
```

You were getting Nullpointer exception because you were setting adapter even it has been initialized. Please, follow the code above.

Answer (score 0):

call  getUsers() this method in main thread before you pass the list to adapter because you list should not be null. Then pass the context and list to adapter like this

```
      users = ArrayList()
      getUsers()
    adapter = UserAdapter(requireContext(),users)
```